# Using Ubuntu 12.04 DHCP server to securely update DNS records in Active Directory

Tags: 12.04, server, dhcp, active-directory

What seems, to me, to be a simple question, apparently isn't.

I have a Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) DHCP server: `isc-dhcp-server`, that works GREAT. No issues and all clients can get an address with no issues.

I also have a Windows 2003 Server Active Directory domain: `corp.local`, e.g. that works great as well.

What I'm trying to do, is to get the Linux DHCP server to SECURELY update the DNS records in Active directory. I can get full functionality if I select "Secure and Non Secure" updates in Windows DNS, but nothing works when I select Secure Only.

I've tried and tried and tried, all to no avail.

- I recognize that I need to somehow share a key or encrypt the data between the Linux DHCP clients and Windows AD/DNS, but I just cant find a how-to.

Any suggestions?

I am NOT interested in having BOTH DHCP and DNS in Linux or BOTH DHCP and DNS in Windows.  I want to keep the Linux DHCP server and Windows AD/DNS.  I just want to find a way to let the Linux DHCP clients securely update their own records in Windows AD.

- When I have "Secure and Non Secure" enabled in Windows DNS, it works - I get the Linux DHCP records in AD.  I also get a "TXT" record that looks like a hash for some kind of secure update.  It's a strong preference (just short of a requirement) to have the updates be secure.

Lastly, I do NOT want to install Samba.  It seems to me to be unnecessary for my environment.

Seems simple to me - a Linux DHCP server that will securely update Windows AD/DNS records.

James